# How to restrict Application only for 10.1 tablet only?

Tags: android

I am making an application which I want to run only for 10.1 tablet only.

Can you please help me?

Comment: `android:supportScreens` attribute inside AndroidManifest.xml can be of your work.

Comment: What about showing your efforts..?

Comment: @PareshMayani: But supportscreens are used for range of devices. eg: the range in which has devices of 10.1 also can have devices with screen of 7.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this to your manifest.

```
<supports-screens
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="false"
    android:normalScreens="false"
    android:smallScreens="false" >
</supports-screens>
```

Answer (score 0):

This  [android.os.build](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html)
contains properties you are interested in.
Build.MODEL, Build.PRODUCT and Build.MANUFACTURER should give you the info you need. They are all String objects.

And also, before installation u cant detect the device model, but after installing the app, you can detect the device model using Build.Model attribute and run ur application as accordingly..

Also you can do like that

```
        String Screen_resolution="Screen Resolution : "+width_pixel+"*"+height_pixel+"\n\n";
        String os_version="Operating System Version : " + android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE+"\n\n";
        String os_api_level="API Level : " + android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK+"\n\n";
        String Model_number=" Model : "+android.os.Build.MODEL+"\n\n";
        String product=" Product : " + android.os.Build.PRODUCT;

tv.setText(Screen_resolution);
        tv.append(os_version);
        tv.append(os_api_level);
        tv.append(Model_number);
        tv.append(product);
```

It will help you

Comment: This has nothing to do with a question. You can't restrict application distribution to devices using this. Only using manifest.